# VB .net Clickonce - check for update but dont update

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce, updates

ok so ive got an updating program via clickonce, I want it to notify the user there is an update but don't actually update the program until an admin logs on and requests the update to go ahead.

I'm checking for updates like this via code

```
If My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed() Then
            If My.Application.Deployment.CheckForUpdate() Then

            MsgBox("Updates are available", vbInformation, "Updates available")
```

Note I haven't called the

```
My.Application.Deployment.Update()
```

to actually update.

When my application checks for updates it displays ok,  but when no one does anything else when it is shut down again and then started up - it seems to revert back to automatically downloading the update on program startup. I have update automatically turned off in the project properties

I tried not checking for updates and the program starts and doesn't update so I'm thinking that just the act of checking and finding an update automatically sets the program to download it next time its started. which id rather it didn't

has anyone come across this issue before?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify this code.  It is with an "updating" action but you'll be able to change this

```
Imports System.Deployment.Application

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
        Dim info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate()
            If (info.UpdateAvailable) Then
                MsgBox("Update wird geladen.")
                updateCheck.Update()
                MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.")
                Application.Restart()
            End If
    Catch : End Try
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Jonnus, thanks very much for the suggestion, although it seems as soon as I include the line `Dim info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate` the next time I start the application it automatically updates without any user input. I have tried taking that check for update line out and it starts ok and doesn't update, as soon as I do any update check the next time I start the program it updates. I really need it to check and notify user but not actually update until an admin logs in to initiate the update, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance have these options selected??

[image]
If you're handling the updates programmatically, you need to untick the "The application should check for updates" box.
Doing this will grey-out the "After" and "Before" radio buttons below it.